# How to measure time interval (different languages)

Tags: timestep

What is the recommended way to measure time intervals for a game loop?

Consider the situation in which a developer is writing their own game loop. Using a third party game engine such that you do not write your own game loop is beyond this question.

In general I want the best API from the standard library, unless there is reason to not use it. The exception being well stablished game development libraries that do not force a game loop on the developers.

---

Ideally the solution is not to use [System time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time). We want something unaffected by time zones, leap seconds, daylight saving, the user messing with the system clock, etc… plus the system time usually has poor resolution for games.

I also found [Time a Function - Rosetta Code](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Time_a_function), it uses system time in some cases.

---

*This is a community wiki.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

### JavaScript

**On the browser**

For code running in the browser, I would strongly advice to use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) as game loop. See [availability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe).

Example:

```
function update(timestamp)
{
    // …
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

`requestAnimationFrame` takes a callback that will be called once per frame, matching the monitor refresh rate. The callback receives a double representing the milliseconds since time origin.

> **The time origin**
> The time origin is a standard time which is considered to be the beginning of the current document's lifetime. It's calculated like this:
>
> - If the script's global object is a Window, the time origin is determined as follows:
> - If the current Document is the first one loaded in the Window, the time origin is the time at which the browser context was created.
> - If during the process of unloading the previous document which was loaded in the window, a confirmation dialog was displayed to let the user confirm whether or not to leave the previous page, the time origin is the time at which the user confirmed that navigating to the new page was acceptable.
> - If neither of the above determines the time origin, then the time origin is the time at which the navigation responsible for creating the window's current Document took place.
> - If the script's global object is a WorkerGlobalScope (that is, the script is running as a web worker), the time origin is the moment at which the worker was created.
> - In all other cases, the time origin is undefined.

-- [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp)

Aside from the game loop, you can get a milliseconds timestamp since time origin by calling [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). See [availability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=high-resolution-time).

Example:

```
var start = performance.now();
// …
var elapsed = performance.now() - start;
```

I want to strongly recommend the talk [Jake Archibald: In The Loop - JSConf.Asia 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) that covers how the browser event loop works and when exactly `requestAnimationFrame` runs.

---

**On Node.js**

Node.js does not have `requestAnimationFrame`. Instead use [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args).

It can be a good idea to use [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#globals_settimeout_callback_delay_args) with the time for the next tick. And to do that effectively, you need to measure time… Thankfully [`performance.now`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#perf_hooks_performance_now) continues to work in Node.js.

---

### Java

In Java you want to use [System.nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// …
long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

I have seen claims that `System.nanoTime` is not thread safe. That is not true, it is thread safe. `System.nanoTime` delegats the request to the operating system, apparently there were some platforms that had bugs.

---

### Python

**With Pygame**

If you are using [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org), you want to call [`clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick). It returns the milliseconds since the last call.

Note: It takes a desired frame rate as argument, and will insert delays if it is been called too soon for that frame rate.

In your game loop, you want to call it every iteration, passing the target frame rate:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    delta = clock.tick(60)
    # …
```

To measure elapsed time you want to use [`get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) instead:

Example:

```
start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
# …
elapsed = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start
```

`pygame.time.get_ticks` returns milliseconds.

**Note**: Pygame uses SDL. In fact, `pygame.time.get_ticks` delegates to [`SDL_GetTicks`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) which returns milliseconds (Uint32) since DSL initialization.

---

**Without Pygame**

If you are not using Pygame, use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter). It returns a float that represents time in (factional) seconds.

Example:

```
start = time.perf_counter()
# …
elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start
```

---

### C

**C on POSIX**

Use [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). You will need the `time.h` header. It takes a clock id that can be either `CLOCK_REALTIME`, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`, or `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` and a pointer to a `timespec`:

```
struct timespec {
    time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */
};
```

The following is example usage:

```
struct timespec start, end;
double elapsed_sec;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
// …
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
elapsed_sec = (end.tv_sec + end.tv_n_sec - start.tv_sec + start.tv_nsec)/1000000000.0;
```

**Note**: `clock_gettime` returns 0 on success. On failure it returns -1 and sets *errno*, it could be `EFAULT` (Invalid pointer) or `EINVAL` (Not supported clock id).

---

**C on Windows**

We will use [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancefrequency):

```
// Once
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
BOOL available = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

LARGE_INTEGER start;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
// …
LARGE_INTEGER end;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
double elapsed_sec = (double)((end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart)/(double)frequency.QuadPart);
```

If `available` is false, you can fallback to [`GetTickCount`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) which gives you milliseconds.

The answer to [the question "Best way to get elapsed time in miliseconds in windows"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26766/10408) has a nice wrapper.

---

**C on OSX, Objective-C**

We will use [`mach_continuous_time`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1646199-mach_continuous_time) from `mach_time.h`.

```
// once
mach_timebase_info_data_t timeBase;
mach_timebase_info(&timeBase);
// unit conversion for nanoseconds
double timeConvert = (double)timeBase.numer / (double)timeBase.denom;

double start = (double)mach_continuous_time() * timeConvert;
//…
double elapsed = ((double)mach_continuous_time() * timeConvert) - start;
```

**Note**: `mach_timebase_info` can fail. It should return `KERN_SUCCESS`, otherwise, you would have to fall back to system time.

---

### C++

Use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now). You will need the `chrono` header.

Example:

```
high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();
// …
high_resolution_clock::time_point end = high_resolution_clock::now();

auto elapses_sec = (end - start).count();
```

See also [`duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

---

**SDL**

If you are using SDL, you can use [`SDL_GetPerformanceCounter`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter) and [`SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency). Example:

```
// Once:
uint64_t PerfCountFrequency = SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();

// …

uint64_t start = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
// …
uint64_t end = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
double elapsed_sec = (double)((end - start) / (double)PerfCountFrequency);
```

**Note**: This method would be equivalent to `SDL_GetTicks` when no better timer is available.

---

### PHP

Use [`hrtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php). When called with `true` as parameter, it returns nanoseconds. `int` or `float` depending on the platform.

Example:

```
$start=hrtime(true);
// …
$end=hrtime(true);
$eta=$end-$start;
```

`hrtime` is stable across requests, and is not susceptible to changes in system time.

**Before PHP 7.3.0**

You want [`microtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php). It uses Unix time and will return a float in seconds if you pass `true` as argument.

Example:

```
$start = microtime(true);
// …
$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
```

`microtime` is stable across requests. It is based on system time.

---

### .NET (C#, VB.NET, etc…)

On Mono or .NET Framework, you want to use [`System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.idle?view=netframework-4.8) for your game loop. It has also been added to .NET Core 3.0.

And for the elapsed time, use a [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8).

Example:

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
// …
var timeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Or for example with `ElapsedMilliseconds`:

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
// …
var milliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

For the game loop we don't need to create an `Stopwatch` every frame. You can compute delta each loop like this:

```
var now = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
var delta = now - milliseconds;
milliseconds = now;
```

`Stopwatch` will use high resolution timers if available. Otherwise, it falls back to system time.

---

### Processing

In processing you can use the [`millis`](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html) function, which as the name suggest gives you milliseconds, from application start in this case.

Example:

```
int start = millis();
// …
int elapsed = millis() - start;
```

`millis` is also available in the ports of processing for **Python** ([`millis`](https://py.processing.org/reference/millis.html)) and **Javascript** ([`millis`](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/millis)).

---

### Ruby

You want [`Process.clock_gettime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime).

Example:

```
starting = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
# …
ending = Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
elapsed = end - start
```

**Note**: If you want to measure the time code takes to run, use [`Benchmark`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

---

### Swift

A in Objective-C/C on OSX, we will use `mach_continuous_time`:

```
var info = mach_timebase_info()
mach_timebase_info(&info)

let start = mach_absolute_time()
// …
let end = mach_absolute_time()
let elapsed_nanoseconds = (end - start) * UInt64(info.numer) / UInt64(info.denom)
```

**Note**: `mach_timebase_info` can fail. It should return `KERN_SUCCESS`, otherwise, you would have to fall back to system time.

---

### GDScript

We have a couple methods that returns monotonic time in Godot:

- `OS.get_ticks_msec` returns an `int` that represents milliseconds since the start of the engine (divide by `1000.0` to get seconds).
- `OS.get_ticks_usec` returns an `int` that represents microseconds since the start of the engine (divide by `1000000.0` to get seconds).

These methods are thread-safe.

*Although those are the units, be aware that the actual resolution depends on the platform.*

So we can get elapsed time like this:

```
var start_microseconds := OS.get_ticks_usec();
// …
var elapsed_microseconds := OS.get_ticks_usec() - startTime;
```

---

*This is a community wiki. Feel free to edit it to add or fix what is in here.*

Comment: I decided to seed this with the top most popular languages according to the last github report at the time of writing... that is why PHP is here.